# Tracking vehicle app by given GPS coordinates

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, gps, geolocation

I am really new for android development and first of all I want to be sure if the approach explained below is possible or not. I have a longitude and attitude data coming from GPS and I want to display an arrow symbol on a Google Map android application. Is it possible? In addition to this, I want to draw line for indicating the road the vehicle passed that I track by GPS. Is there such a kind of implementation samples? I have a look at many videos and Web sites but have not found such a sample exactly performing these requirements. Could you please clarify me regarding to this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes possible...see these links..
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/code-samples

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView
https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils

https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples
https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-05-12-broadcasting-realtime-location-data-for-android-live-updating-map/

Happy coding!!

Comment: This is very much a link-only answer.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. It is really very helpful, but as I have not enough reputation, I just marked it as answer without voting up :(